# In a C*-algebra, does $|xyz| \leq |xz|^\frac{1}{2} | y| \ | xz|^\frac{1}{2}$ hold?

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $x,y,z$ be elements of a C*-algebra $A$. Does the inequality
$$|xyz| \leq |xz|^\frac{1}{2}    | y|  \ | xz|^\frac{1}{2}$$
hold in the positive cone of $A$? Here $|x| := (x^*x)^\frac{1}{2}$.

- If $y= 1$, this is an equality.
- If $z=1$, this is $ |xy| \leq |x|^\frac{1}{2} |y| |x|^\frac{1}{2}$, which I'm already not too sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm it seems the answer must be "no".

Take $z = 1$, and $x$ to be a projection $e$. So, the inequality to be proved becomes
$$|ey| \leq e | y| e.$$

Now, take $y$ to be a partial isometry $w$ with $ww^* = e$ and $w^*w = e'$ where $e'$ is orthogonal to $e$. Then, $|ey| = e$ while $e|y| e = ee'e = 0 $, but $e \leq 0$ fails (assuming $e \neq 0$).

Sorry for the apparently silly question...

---

Although it's probably quite clear, I guess I'd may as well add that the counterexample outlined above already crops up when $A = \operatorname{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$. Just take
\begin{align*}
x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &&
y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &&
z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
to see the inequality fail.